# excel quotes in formula question

Tags: sql, excel, vba

i have a column with this data:

```
IT_AMPH
IT_BARB
IT_BENZ
IT_BUP
SOMA
```

i want the column next to it to be literarely

```
=like "*,IT_AMPH,*"
=like "*,IT_BARB,*"
=like "*,IT_BENZ,*"
etc
```

please note that i want the equal signed to be displayed, exactly as shown above

what would be the formula for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should do it..

```
="=like ""*," & othercolumn & ",*"""
```

Answer (score 1):

```
="=like ""*," & A1 & ",*"
```

Excel is smart enough to know that the string you are creating is not itself a formula. Btw, this really belongs on `superuser.com` instead of stackoverflow.